# How to create a fixed-length array in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I create arrays using this method. I want to create fixed-length array  that contains only 20 elements.

```js
this.state{
    array:[]
}

onInputChange(e){
    const name=e.target.value;
    this.setState({ array:name })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array#fill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill)

```js
const arr = Array(20).fill(1)
console.log(arr)
```

This will not be *fixed* as you can't fix an array's length, but you can do according checks in order not to push anything to this array once created. You can create a  fixed Object however, using [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal)

#### UPDATE:

Apparently, you can use `Object.seal()` on arrays too:

```js
const object1 = Array(10).fill(0)

Object.seal(object1);
object1[2] = 24;
console.log(object1)

object1.push(8)
console.log(object1)

object1.pop()
console.log(object1)
```

And if you use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) it also doesn't allow any changes in the array. You can still change the values of indices using seal()

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're trying to test something in JSX or just to print there a fixed number of elements, this is great and worked for me.
Hopefully, this will help you.

`{Array.from({length:3}).map((element,index) => <p>{element}  {index} </p>)}`